# Archlinux/Pacman list installed packages with description

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

**How do I list installed packages (by user) with a short description?**
When I search for packages to install: `pacman -Ss zsh`, I get following result:
`extra/zsh 5.7.1-1 [installed]
    A very advanced and programmable command interpreter (shell) for UNIX`
I would like to get the same result using something like `pacman -Qe`.

Comment: This WiKi may help https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta.

Comment: `pacman -Qs` gives me the desired explanation, but it cannot be combined with the `-e` option. So I tried piping some outputs together using xargs and ended with a for loop: `for i in \`pacman -Qe | cut -d' ' -f1\`; do pacman -Qs $i | grep -A1 --color "local/$i\s"; done`

Answer (score 2):

These work fast on my end

This will give full info of pacman -Qe results. It does pacman -Qi on each line of the pacman -Qe output

```
for line in "$(pacman -Qqe)"; do pacman -Qi $(echo "$line"); done
```

This will generate the same output as the loop you made but without doing a pacman search on each line. Uses pipes and perl to format the output of the above command

```
for line in "$(pacman -Qqe)"; do pacman -Qi $(echo "$line") ; done | perl -pe 's/ +/ /gm' | perl -pe 's/^(Groups +: )(.*)/$1($2)/gm' | perl -0777 -pe 's/^Name : (.*)\nVersion :(.*)\nDescription : ((?!None).*)?(?:.|\n)*?Groups :((?! \(None\)$)( )?.*)?(?:.|\n(?!Name))+/local\/$1$2$4\n    $3/gm' | grep -A1 --color -P "^[^\s]+"
```

Same as above but didn't add "local/" to beginning of each package name

```
for line in "$(pacman -Qqe)"; do pacman -Qi $(echo "$line") ; done | perl -pe 's/ +/ /gm' | perl -pe 's/^(Groups +: )(.*)/$1($2)/gm' | perl -0777 -pe 's/^Name : (.*)\nVersion :(.*)\nDescription : ((?!None).*)?(?:.|\n)*?Groups :((?! \(None\)$)( )?.*)?(?:.|\n(?!Name))+/$1$2$4\n    $3/gm' | grep -A1 --color -P "^[^\s]+"
```

Answer (score 2):

This command gives the description in the same line.

```
expac -H M '%-20n\t%10d' $(pacman -Qe)
```

It is made from some commands found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Not_in_a_specified_group,_repository_or_meta_package) in the archwiki.